# Binomial trees using forest package

Tags: tikz-trees, trees

I need to draw a 3-period tree with different elements at each stage, for example:

the upper path:

(12)(12) ---> ()

the lower path:

(13)(12) ---> (123)

how can I draw such a tree?

Edit:

something like this but for a 3-period tree using the forest package to make it more neat:

```
    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\tikzset{bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped]
\matrix (tree) [%
      matrix of nodes,
      minimum size=0.1cm,
      column sep=3cm,
      row sep=0.1cm,nodes={text width=8em}
          ]
    {
          &   &  \\
          & {$()$} &   \\
     $(12)$ &   &  \\
          &  {$(123)$} &   \\
          &   &  \\
    };
    \node[bullet,right=0mm of tree-3-1.east](b-3-1){};
    \node[bullet,left=0mm of tree-2-2.west](b-2-2){};
    \node[bullet,left=0mm of tree-4-2.west](b-4-2){};
    \draw[->] (b-3-1) -- (b-2-2) node [midway,above] {$(12)$};
    \draw[->] (b-3-1) -- (b-4-2) node [midway,below] {$(13)$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you know that `forest` exists, can you post a minimal document that shows what you've tried and what you're having problems with? Also, for people not in your particular discipline, your terms won't mean much, or the notation you're using in your question, even though we might know how to help you draw the tree. Furthermore, there are plenty of examples on the site, many with `forest`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+tree

Comment: I used a different code from another question but I want unique labelling for each step

Comment: So show us what you've done and what you want.

Comment: the p, p^2, (1-p), (1-p)^2 and p(1-p)  I want to rename them

Comment: Where did this code come from? Can you edit your question to include a link to its source (I'm assuming a question here on the site.)

Comment: I don't understand the question. As @AlanMunn suggested.

Comment: @AlanMunn Munn, the values p, p^2 etc, I want to change them to say x and z, how can I do this?

Comment: @AlanMunn https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227414/draw-5-period-binomial-tree answer from Tonio

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478858/how-to-rotate-a-decision-tree/478906#478906

Comment: @Zarko thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Alan Munn and cfr I also do not understand the problem. You could make the code you have a bit more versatile by using the auto enumeration that can be found in the forest manual on p. 52, and then all you need to do is to add some basic pgf functions. You may want to adjust the items `"cat","mole","duck","marmot",...` to your needs.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{forest}
\bracketset{action character=@}
\def\pexp#1#2{\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{int(#1)}\pgfmathparse{\x>0?(\x>1?"#2^{\x}":"#2"):""}\pgfmathresult}%
\def\btreelabel#1#2{node[midway,sloped,font=\scriptsize,/forest,if n=1{/tikz/below}{/tikz/above}]{$\pexp{#1}{p}\pexp{#2}{(1-p)}$}}%
\def\btree#1#2#3{,grow=east,l*=2,edge label=\btreelabel{#1}{#2},if={#3>0}{append=[@\btree{#1}{#2+1}{#3-1}],append=[@\btree{#1+1}{#2}{#3-1}]}{}}%

\xdef\LstItems{"cat","mole","duck","marmot","koala","rhino","bear","hare","opossum"}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{mitem}{1}{%
\begingroup%
\pgfmathparse{{\LstItems}[#1-1]}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=0},tempcounta=1,
before typesetting nodes={for descendants={content/.pgfmath={mitem(int(tempcounta))}, tempcounta+=1}}
[pft@\btree{0}{0}{2}]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: Answer to version 2 of your question.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east,l sep=4em,s sep=3em,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill}
[,label=left:{$(12)$}
 [,label=right:{$()$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{(12)}}]
 [,label=right:{$(123)$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{(13)}}]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**LAST ADDENDUM**:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east,l sep=4em,s sep=3em,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill}
[,label=left:{$(12)$}
 [,label=above:{$()$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(12)$}}
  [,label=right:$X$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$x$}}]
  [,label=right:$Y$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$y$}}]
 ]
 [,label=below:{$(123)$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{(13)}}
  [,label=right:$U$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$u$}}]
  [,label=right:$V$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$v$}}]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the values p, p^2 etc, I want to change them to say x and z, how can I do this?

Comment: how do I change the probabilities on the trees to something different? for example I'm drawing trees for a particular group, so I need different elements

Comment: I want a 3 period binomial tree with 4 terminal nodes as in your answer, however I want to rename the associated probabilities labelled on the line segments.

Comment: please look at my edited answer

Comment: Also, how can I 'push' the (12) closer to the tree?

Comment: @Math Please have a look at the addendum to my answer.

Comment: thank you, now can you extend this exact same notion to a 3-period tree?

Comment: but on the 3-period line segments, I would like to change the labelling.

Comment: my initial question was on a 3-period tree..

Comment: I clearly mentioned I need to this to be a 3-period tree and gave a 2-period example as I didn't know how to extend it. If you are tired and cant be bothered answering please do not get upset.

Comment: thank you, I'm sorry about earlier.

Comment: how would you style the marmot?  (think blue or boldfaced)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478858/%20how-to-rotate-a-decision-tree/478906#478906) (which was significantly improved by edit of @marmoth, thank you again!):

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\forestset{
     declare toks={elo}{font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt, midway, sloped}, % Edge Label Options
     anchors/.style={anchor=#1,child anchor=#1,parent anchor=#1},
     dot/.style={tikz+={\fill (.child anchor) circle[radius=3pt];}},
     decision edge label/.style 2 args= {
        edge label/.expanded={node[anchor=#1,\forestoption{elo}]{$#2$}}
     },
     decision/.style={if n=1
     {decision edge label={south}{#1}}
     {decision edge label={north}{#1}}
     },
     decision tree/.style={
     for tree={grow'=east,
     s sep=1em,l=13ex,
     if n children=0{anchors=west}{
            if n=1{anchors=south east}{anchors=north east}
                                   },
     },
     anchors=east, 
     dot, for descendants=dot,
     delay={for descendants={split option={content}{;}{content,decision}}},
      }
    }

    \begin{forest} decision tree
[(12)
    [(X);(12),
        [A;a]
        [B;b]
     ]
     [(123);(13),
         [C;c]
         [D;d]
     ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Have you tried sometimes `istgame` package to create a tree?

Comment: @Sebastiano, no. But i sow some answer here using this package. I'm more interested to improve my knowledge about `forest`.